# How to define text css style in my themes folder to work with wysiwyg editor?

Tags: theming

Bold text and Italic text are not working in ckeditor and I think it is because I have sites/all/themes/mytheme/styles/mytheme.css somehow not communicating with it.

Other text formats like strikethrough and underline are working fine for ckeditor.

So do I need to declare a property in mytheme.css to allow the editor to work?

I don't have the eric meyer reset file included or anything , just the add on css changes I made to my theme but don't see how that is stopping the strong and italic tags from not working because my changes were made for specific div ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i usually add a separate .css file for the editors, this is only possible via the [WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), in the settings of that text-format.
you can even add special classes and block-formats the user can choose then.

to see what's happening, you can inspect the editor normally in your browser, and should see the problem.